# Update Child state from Parent using Context in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context

I have a few buttons and "view all" button. The individual buttons load the coresponding data of that index or will show all the data by clicking the "view all" button. Problem I am running into is when I click my "view all" button in the parent it's not updating the state in the child component. On mounting it works as normal but on event handler in the "view all" it doesn't update. Any thoughts on where I am going wrong here?

JS:

```
...
const Context = createContext(false);

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  },
  orange: {
    color: theme.palette.getContrastText(deepOrange[500]),
    backgroundColor: deepOrange[500],
    border: "4px solid black"
  },
  info: {
    margin: "10px"
  },
  wrapper: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  contentWrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  elWrapper: {
    opacity: 0,
    "&.active": {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
}));

const ToggleItem = ({ id, styles, discription }) => {
  const { activeViewAll, handleChange } = useContext(Context);
  const [toggleThisButton, setToggleThisButton] = useState();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggleThisButton((prev) => !prev);
    handleChange(discription, !toggleThisButton);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Avatar
        className={toggleThisButton && !activeViewAll ? styles.orange : ""}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {id}
      </Avatar>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(toggleThisButton)}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const ToggleContainer = ({ className, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {selected.map((item, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>Content {item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const data = ["first", "second", "third"];
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [activeViewAll, setActiveViewAll] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveViewAll(true);
    setSelected([...data]);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (val, action) => {
    let newVal = [];
    if (activeViewAll) {
      selected.splice(0, 3);
      setActiveViewAll(false);
    }
    if (action) {
      newVal = [...selected, val];
    } else {
      // If toggle off, then remove content from selected state
      newVal = selected.filter((v) => v !== val);
    }
    console.log("action", action);
    setSelected(newVal);
  };

  const handleViewAll = () => {
    console.log("all clicked");
    setActiveViewAll(true);
    setSelected([...data]);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ activeViewAll, handleChange }}>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <Avatar
          className={activeViewAll ? classes.orange : null}
          onClick={handleViewAll}
        >
          <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", textAlign: "center" }}>
            View All
          </span>
        </Avatar>
        {data.map((d, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              <ToggleItem id={id} styles={classes} discription={d} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
        <ToggleContainer styles={classes} selected={selected} />
      </div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

Codesanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/72166087-forked-jvn59i?file=/src/App.js:260-3117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue seems to be that you are mixing up the management of the boolean `activeViewAll` state with the `selected` state.

## Solution

When `activeViewAll` is true, pass the `data` array as the `selected` prop value to the `ToggleContainer` component, otherwise pass what is *actually* selected, the `selected` state.

Simplify the handlers. The `handleViewAll` callback only toggles the view all state to true, and the `handleChange` callback toggles the view all state back to false and selects/deselects the data item.

```
function App() {
  const data = ["first", "second", "third"];
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]); // none selected b/c view all true
  const [activeViewAll, setActiveViewAll] = useState(true); // initially view all

  const handleChange = (val, action) => {
    setActiveViewAll(false); // deselect view all
    setSelected(selected => {
      if (action) {
        return [...selected, val];
      } else {
        return selected.filter(v => v !== val)
      }
    });
  };

  const handleViewAll = () => {
    setActiveViewAll(true); // select view all
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ activeViewAll, handleChange }}>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <Avatar
          className={activeViewAll ? classes.orange : null}
          onClick={handleViewAll}
        >
          <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", textAlign: "center" }}>
            View All
          </span>
        </Avatar>
        {data.map((d, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              <ToggleItem id={id} styles={classes} discription={d} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
        <ToggleContainer
          styles={classes}
          selected={activeViewAll ? data : selected} // pass all data, or selected only
        />
      </div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

In the `ToggleContainer` don't use the array index as the React key since you are mutating the array. Use the element value since they are unique and changing the order/index doesn't affect the value.

```
const ToggleContainer = ({ className, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {selected.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>Content {item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Update

Since it is now understood that you want to not remember what was previously selected before toggling `activeViewAll` then when toggling true clear the `selected` state array. Instead of duplicating the selected state in the children components, pass the `selected` array in the context and computed a derived `isSelected` state. This maintains a single source of truth for what is selected and removes the need to "synchronize" state between components.

```
const ToggleItem = ({ id, styles, description }) => {
  const { handleChange, selected } = useContext(Context);
  const isSelected = selected.includes(description);

  const handleClick = () => {
    handleChange(description);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Avatar
        className={isSelected ? styles.orange : ""}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {id}
      </Avatar>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(isSelected)}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const ToggleContainer = ({ className, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {selected.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>Content {item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Update the `handleChange` component to take only the selected value and determine if it needs to add/remove the value.

```
export default function App() {
  const data = ["first", "second", "third"];
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [activeViewAll, setActiveViewAll] = useState(true);

  const handleChange = (val) => {
    setActiveViewAll(false);
    setSelected((selected) => {
      if (selected.includes(val)) {
        return selected.filter((v) => v !== val);
      } else {
        return [...selected, val];
      }
    });
  };

  const handleViewAll = () => {
    setActiveViewAll(true);
    setSelected([]);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ activeViewAll, handleChange, selected }}>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <Avatar
          className={activeViewAll ? classes.orange : null}
          onClick={handleViewAll}
        >
          <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", textAlign: "center" }}>
            View All
          </span>
        </Avatar>
        {data.map((d, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={d}>
              <ToggleItem id={id} styles={classes} description={d} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
        <ToggleContainer
          styles={classes}
          selected={activeViewAll ? data : selected}
        />
      </div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit update-child-state-from-parent-using-context-in-react]